# Can 0 be a tight upper bound of -4n?

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, big-o-notation, upper-bound

I'm newbie in algorithm time complexity.
I had a function, `f(n) = 2n2 - 4n`.
I have to proof that `f(n) = O(n2)`.

We can take it like this:
f(n) = 2n<sup>2</sup> - 4n
$\le$ 2n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>2</sup> $\le$ `3n2`

What if I just omit the `-4n`? Because, 0 is the upper bound of `-4n`? So, it becomes like:
f(n) = 2n<sup>2</sup> - 4n
$\le$ 2n<sup>2</sup> + 0 $\le$ `2n2`

Comment: Nothing bad in it - it is correct. But I'm afraid of your title.

Comment: @zkutch Would you mind editing? If it is awkward.

Comment: The first argument is unnecessary, 2n²-4n<2n² is enough. (You needn't consider n=0).

Comment: @Ashraful Alam Shakil, You see, usually, tight we called $\Theta$ type estimation - from this point of view it's hard to say, that $0$ is tight for $-4n$.